# FosJsRoutingBundle with '_locale'

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

For example, i have a script like this:

```
 Routing.generate('_moderation_profile_confirm',{'id':objectId,'_locale':'en'})
```

is correct, but when i remove the '_locale' parameter, it send me error like '_locale' must be set. 
my route name _moderation_profile_confirm contains a '_locale' prefix but how can i send the 'current' locale for the routing manager?

Answer (score 0):

I supouse you are in twig template:

You can use this shorthand and get current locale:

```
Routing.generate('_moderation_profile_confirm',{'id':objectId,'_locale':'{{ app.session.locale }} '})
```

Comment: I'm in a pure JavaScript file, and i just wanna to know if this locale option is prerequisite.

Answer (score 0):

I copy here the response I proposed here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35223108/279326

To set the request locale to all your call to Routing.generate, you can override this method and add the {{app.request.locale}} param in every call. The following script has to be executed in a twig template and after including routing script.

```
<!-- Include JSRouting libs & exposed routes -->
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', {"callback": "fos.Router.setData"}) }}"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        // change name of initial method
        Routing.generateImpl = Routing.generate;
        // override generate fonction by adding a default _locale from request locale
        Routing.generate = function (url, params) {
            var paramsExt = {};
            if (params) {
                paramsExt = params;
            }
            if (!paramsExt._locale){
                paramsExt._locale = '{{ app.request.locale }}';
            }
            return Routing.generateImpl(url, paramsExt);
        }
    })
</script>
```

Now you can use Routing.generate transparently without worry about the _locale param !

```
// in any JS file
var url = Routing.generate('mypath');
var url2 = Routing.generate('another path', {param: 1});
```

To clarify the code, it could be possible to isolate the previous script in a js file. For that a global variable has to be defined.

```
<!-- for exemple in the <head> of the page -->
<script>
    var REQUEST_LOCALE = '{{ app.request.locale }}';
</script>
```

And so in the script you can use REQUEST_LOCALE

```
// this line
paramsExt._locale = '{{ app.request.locale }}';
// has to be replaced by
paramsExt._locale = REQUEST_LOCALE;
```