# Symfony, fos_js_routing and problems with "_locale"

Tags: php, symfony, routes

this is my app/routing.yml

> FrontendBundle:
>
> ```
> resource: "@FrontendBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
> prefix:   /{_locale}/
> requirements:
>     _locale: en|es
> ```
>
> BackendBundle:
>
> ```
> resource: "@BackendBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
> prefix:   /{_locale}/app
> requirements:
>     _locale: en|es
> ```
>
> fos_js_routing:
>       resource: "@FOSJsRoutingBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing.xml"

and this is my BackendBundle\Resources\Config\routing.yml

> getModelsFromMake:
>
> ```
> pattern:  /getModelsFromMake/{idMake}
>
> defaults: { _controller: BackendBundle:Backend:getModelFromMake }
> options:
>     expose: true
> ```

and my problems is when i do a ajax call like this:

> $.ajax({
>           type: "POST",
>
> ```
>     url: Routing.generate('getModelsFromMake'),
>     data: {
>         idMake: $('#make').val(),
>     },
>     dataType: "json",
>     success: function(data) { console.log("All OK"); },
>     error: function()       { console.log("ERROR"); }
> });
> ```

the chrome inspector tell me:

```
Uncaught Error: The route "getModelsFromMake" requires the parameter "_locale".
```

any idea to solve this?

EDIT 1:

in my layout I have this:

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}"></script>
> <script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', {"callback": "fos.Router.setData"}) }}"></script>
> ```

EDIT 2:

if I run the command "php app/console fos:js-routing:debug" I get this:

```
Name              Method Pattern
getModelsFromMake ANY    /{_locale}/app/getModelsFromMake
```

Comment: Is that code contained in a view?

Comment: no, the javascript is in another file (Resources\backend.js) and in my layout i imported the files like this:


    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}"></script>


    <script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', {"callback": "fos.Router.setData"}) }}"></script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to insert this snippet of code before your ajax

```
<script>
    var locale= {{ app.request.locale }} ;
</script>
```

and modify your script as follows

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST",

    url: Routing.generate('getModelsFromMake', array('_locale' => locale)),
    data: {
        idMake: $('#make').val(),
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) { console.log("All OK"); },
    error: function()       { console.log("ERROR"); }
});
```

Comment: Hi DonCallisto, the problem is when my js file is apart of my twig file, and I can't access to `{{ app.request.locale }}`, but yes, if I put 'en' or 'es' with hardcode the route works fine.

Comment: @RogerGuasch: you don't have to add first snippet of code into js directly, just put it inside twig, before calling your external js. Could you try?

Comment: it's a shame that jsRouting doesn't use default locale automatically like twig expression {{ path() }} do

Answer (score 5):

To set the request locale to all your call to Routing.generate, you can override this method and add the {{app.request.locale}} param in every call. The following script has to be executed in a twig template and after including routing script.

```
<!-- Include JSRouting libs & exposed routes -->
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', {"callback": "fos.Router.setData"}) }}"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        // change name of initial method
        Routing.generateImpl = Routing.generate;
        // override generate fonction by adding a default _locale from request locale
        Routing.generate = function (url, params) {
            var paramsExt = {};
            if (params) {
                paramsExt = params;
            }
            if (!paramsExt._locale){
                paramsExt._locale = '{{ app.request.locale }}';
            }
            return Routing.generateImpl(url, paramsExt);
        }
    })
</script>
```

Now you can use Routing.generate transparently without worry about the _locale param !

```
// in any JS file
var url = Routing.generate('mypath');
var url2 = Routing.generate('another path', {param: 1});
```

To clarify the code, it could be possible to isolate the previous script in a js file. For that a global variable has to be defined as told by @DonCallisto .

```
<!-- for exemple in the <head> of the page -->
<script>
    var REQUEST_LOCALE = '{{ app.request.locale }}';
</script>
```

And so in the script you can use REQUEST_LOCALE

```
// this line
paramsExt._locale = '{{ app.request.locale }}';
// has to be replaced by
paramsExt._locale = REQUEST_LOCALE;
```

Comment: this is an excellent solution. I wish it were already incorporated into FOSJsRoutingBundle.